# one memcache namespace per entity kind

Tags: google-app-engine, namespaces, memcached

"one memcache namespace per entity kind" Is a good idea? Any other impacts when compared to single namespace?

```
 MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService("K1");
 MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService("K2");
 MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService("K3");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

bad idea.

There's a bunch of memecache APIs like cas_multi() which allows you to work with multiple keys in one efficient call.  They'll require all your keys to be within one namespace though, so splitting namespace by kind will mean you're artificially limiting yourself.

Just use a prefix per kind when generating your keys.